# SQL script modifying login permissions

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting

I'm trying to build a script to create a database and login that access only that database but I'm having. here is my code

```
:setvar ID "test"

USE master;
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [GUST\$(ID)]; 
GO
USE [$(ID)];
GO
DROP USER [GUST\$(ID)];
GO
USE master;
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[$(ID)] TO [GUST\$(ID)];
GO
```

and the error is `Cannot drop the user 'GUST\($ID)', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean  `[GUEST\$(ID)] and not`[GUST\$(ID)]. SO does not allow to correct this.
The guest user is ordinarily disabled according [technet.microsoft.com](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx) and can not be dropped according [DROP USER (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189438.aspx)